# how to bind properties of different values when neither is String?

Tags: javafx

I'm writing a simple component - a slider which I use to select a date accompanied by a datepicker which can be used to do precise selection. I want to bind them together so that they always sync their value.

Slider's value is a `Double`, DatePicker value is a `LocalDate`. I modeled slider's value to be "number of years since start date":

```java
LocalDate timelineStart = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1);
LocalDate timelineEnd = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1);
LocalDate selectedDate = LocalDate.now();

double daysInYear = 365.25;
double minValue = 0.0;
double maxValue = (timelineEnd.toEpochDay() - timelineStart.toEpochDay()) / daysInYear;
Slider slider = new Slider(minValue, maxValue, maxValue);
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(selectedDate);
...
```

Now I have to bind those 2 parameters together. What I expected to do is something like:

```java
Bindings.bindBidirectional(slider.valueProperty(), datePicker.valueProperty(), (magic));
```

where magic would be a converter between `LocalDate` and `Double`, something like (I'm inventing API at this point)

```
new Converter<LocalDate, Double> {
 Double to(LocalDate) {
   (date.toEpochDay() - startDay) / daysInYear
 }

 LocalDate from(Double value) {
   LocalDate.ofEpochDay((long) (startDay + daysInYear * value));
 }
}
```

But I can't find any API to convert between types that are not Strings. There is a `StringConverter<T>` which I could use to convert Strings to LocalDates or doubles and other way around, but I can't find any generic `Converter<T,U>`... Am I missing something?

So far I did binding manually with listeners:

```java
datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    slider.setValue(localDateToSliderValue(newValue))
);
slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    datePicker.setValue(sliderValueToLocalDate(newValue.doubleValue()))
);
```

but it feels a bit like re-inventing the wheel. Is there better way?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be something like this in the API currently. You may get into an issue with your code though, if the mapping is not a bijection: You're basically updating a property from a listener to it in that case (unless putting a value though both transformations results in an object equal to the original one). You may want to take a look at my suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218214/2991525 Rewriting to use an interface for the conversion shouldn't be hard..

Comment: You'll have to implement this yourself (unless there's a third-party library that provides this functionality). Take a look at how JavaFX implements bidirectional bindings: [`BidirectionalBinding`](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/BidirectionalBinding.java). The implementations involving a `StringConverter` are on line `723` and below; you can model your implementation off of those. You'll need to create some sort of `Converter<T, U>` interface.

Comment: If you want a quick solution, simply let `A` listens for changes in `B`, and vice versa. If you want an elegant method, you have to write new API yourself, based on `BidirectionalBinding` class from API. If you choose to DIY, and if you want to handle unbind use-case, then you need to override `equals()` and create an additional `Binding` class that can be used for doing unbind (the rule is if the two instances of custom binding objects are on the same properties, then they are equal).

Comment: The solution @fabian mentioned seems like exactly what I need. Given how simple this is to implement I somewhat understand now why there was no provided API. Thanks.